# Can I get a PAL physical copy of Ragnarok Odyssey?

Tags: ps-vita, ragnarok-odyssey

Ragnarok Odyssey is about 1.5 GB to download,  I've been looking for a physical copy of it but everywhere I look they point out that it's a NTSC copy, while I normally wouldn't mind since the Vita is Region Free, DLC isn't and PSN accounts are tied to the memory card.

So I'm wondering if Ragnarok Odyssey was released in PAL as a physical copy, I know it's been released as a physical copy in the US, but some games released in the US as physical copies were then released in PAL as download only (Shin Megami Tensei Persona, for example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. [According to a comment on the PS.Blog](http://blog.eu.playstation.com/2013/02/06/ragnarok-odyssey-release-date-announced-demo-out-today/#comment-344145), the game is digital only in the PAL regions.

> **Q:** Ragnarok Odyssey will release as Retail title or only digital?
>   **A:** Digital only.

Comment: just wondering, my mum found this while i was at work http://www.ebay.com.au/itm/Ragnarok-Odyssey-PS-Vita-Import-BRAND-NEW-SEALED-/190813580807?pt=UK_PC_Video_Games_Video_Games_JS&hash=item2c6d602e07, she showed it to me when i got back and i told her to message the seller cause they said PAL but it was a US Image, the seller responded that it was PAL and my mum brought it, could she have been tricked cause i told her to wait till tomorrow but she jumped the gun and im expected to pay her back when it comes in

Comment: I doubt there's a "secret" retail PAL version that only this seller has access to. I assume the fact he states "IMPORT" in the title proves otherwise.

Comment: thanks, i'll wait till the game comes in, if it's NTSC then i'll make sure my mum gets a full refund and the seller is pointed out for providing false information cause as you can see on the link, they say PAL and my mum did ask if it was PAL or NTSC and they said PAL, i had her ask not because i was worried about region restriction, i was asking in terms of DLC